# How to make a URL redirect me to a different URL

Tags: windows-10, gmail, redirection, url, outlook.com

I've already seen a few things about /etc/hosts but I don't really get them, so I'm asking for help. I just synced my Hotmail account with my Gmail but I prefer to type hotmail.com (redirects to Outlook) instead of mail.google.com out of habit. Is there a way to make the URL "hotmail.com" redirect me to mail.google.com instead of Outlook.com? I use Mozilla Firefox 54.0.1 on Windows 10 Pro.
I'm pretty simple-minded, so please don't blow my mind with programming stuff. Thanks in advance for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a firefox extension such as [redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/redirector/) which is much simpler for what you want to get.

Just write that hotmail.com will redirect to mail.google.com and it should work fine.

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I tried it with Wildcard and Regular Expression, and hotmail.com/ (note the /) but it still redirects me to Outlook.com. Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I dont have access to firefox right now but I have tried a similar extension in chrome: **switcheroo**, and I configured it like **From: hotmail.com** --> **To: gmail.com** and it worked fine (I used gmail as I am used to it rather than mail.google.com.

If you have a chance, give a try to chrome and this extension and if it works, the problem might be in the firefox configuration / extension.